# Rails query with more than one nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, rails-activerecord

I have two models in my rails 5 application:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In my data base I have for example two post with 2 different tags each. How can I search my post by two specifics tags (tag.title="tagname1" AND tag.title="tagname2"):

```
Post.includes(:tags).where(tag: {title: "tagName1"}).where(tag: {title: 
"tagName2"})
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

```
Post.joins(:tags)
  .where(tags: { title: ['tag1', 'tag2'] })
  .group('posts.id')
  .having('count(tags.post_id) = ?', 2)
```

### Assumptions:

- you have a uniqueness validation for tag.title for each post like the following:

  ```
  class Tag < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post

    validates :title, uniqueness: { scope: :post }
  end
  ```

  ... otherwise, solution above won't work, because:

  ```
  # it will still also match the following Post
  Post(id: 1)
    Tag(post_id: 1, title: 'tag1')
    Tag(post_id: 1, title: 'tag1')

  # but that you only want instead those like the following:
  Post(id: 2)
    Tag(post_id: 2, title: 'tag1')
    Tag(post_id: 2, title: 'tag2')
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use arel for cleaner queries.

```
Post.joins(:tags).where(Tag.arel_table[:title].in(['tagName1', 'tagName']))
```

Comment: You will get posts with both, as it will do `OR` operation when you use it like this. This is just `SQL` IN statement

Comment: hmm I wonder if the OP wants to get Posts having both tags, and therefore not OR

Comment: sorry @Nermin , I mean that I need get the post with "tagName1" tag AND "tagNam" tag, no OR

Answer (score 0):

search post by two specifics tags

```
Post.includes(:tags).where("tags.title IN (?)",["tagName1", "tagName"]).references(:tag)
```

This will return all posts having tags.title either "tagName1" or "tagName"

Comment: @jorgeregidor Exactly you'll get the same.

Comment: sorry @Gabbar , I mean that I need get the post with "tagName1" tag AND "tagNam" tag, no OR

Comment: @jorgeregidor  `Post.includes(:tags).where("tags.title  = ? AND ?","tagName1", "tagName").references(:tag)`
Probably this is what you want. ?